# how to append a circle obj in textPath

Tags: svg

i am working on a svg application. Problem i am facing in these days is that i have to append a circle in a textpath instead of a text string, how will be it possible to implement that, any help will be awesome, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here, 
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/textpath-element.html

you will find:

```
<defs>
    <path id="myTextPath"
          d="M75,20
             a1,1 0 0,0 100,0
           "
            />
</defs>

<text x="10" y="100" style="stroke: #000000;">
  <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath" >
        Text along a curved path...
  </textPath>
</text>
```

Credits to Jakob Jenkov!